# Why does nyc only capture files from the main process of my Electron process?

Tags: electron, ava, nyc

I use [ava](https://istanbul.js.org/) in combination with the testing framework [nyc](https://github.com/avajs/ava) for my Electron app. After executing my tests I noticed that only  files from the main process are captured.

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
"ava-ts": "nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text ava-ts",
```

Can anyone explain me why that is and how to fix it? Thanks so much!

Comment: https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#selecting-files-for-coverage Idk if that will help